# Outlook Web Add In get Mailbox Folder Name

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am building an Outlook Web Add-in. When a message is opened I want to check if the message is in the Inbox, Sent Mail etc. and process accordingly. I do not know how to obtain that information, i.e., whether the message is in Inbox, Sent Mail etc. I have attached a snippet of code where I would like to obtain that information.

```
Office.onReady(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Get if message is in Inbox, Sent Mail etc. here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

As a workaround, [get message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#GetMessage) can be used to obtain the ParentFolderId and then can be passed that onto [get folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#GetFolder) to retrieve details about the folder, including the name. We have documentation about [Outlook Add-Ins and REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api) with an example about getting a message using the ItemId.